# No display of new row in the page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-table

I have successfully compiled the JS code but there is no output of the event taking the form values onto the table

```
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Add or Update Item</h2>
        <form id="addform" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="additembox">
                <label>Item No. </label><input id="itemno" type="text" name="id" pattern="#\d\d\d" title="#xxx, x=digits">
            </div>
            <div class="additembox">
                <label>Item Name </label><input id="itemname" type="text" name="iname">
            </div>
            <div class="additembox">
                <label>Price </label><input id="price" type="text" name="price">
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Update">
            <button id="sub" onclick="addr()">Add</button>

        </form>
    </div>
    <table id="addtable">
        <tr>
            <th>Sl. no</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Hotel</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addr(){
    var tab = document.getElementById('addtable');
    //getting form values
    var ino=document.getElementById('itemno').value;
    var iname=document.getElementById('itemname').value;
    var p=document.getElementById('price').value;
    var rowcount = tab.rows.length;
    var row = tab.insertRow(rowcount);
    row.insertCell(0).innerText = 'ino';
    row.insertCell(1).innerText = 'iname';
}
```

I've tried loading the values in the form and clicking the button.

I expect the output to be displayed on the local web page, but it is not displayed.

Comment: Please edit the code and complete `addr` function

Comment: i have completed the function. Sorry for the mistake during post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This two lines `row.insertCell(0).innerText = 'ino';row.insertCell(1).innerText = 'iname';`is adding ino & iname as string but you need the variable value. Also use button type `button` or use `event.preventDefault`

```js
function addr() {
  var tab = document.getElementById('addtable');
  //getting form values
  var ino = document.getElementById('itemno').value;
  var iname = document.getElementById('itemname').value;
  var p = document.getElementById('price').value;
  var rowcount = tab.rows.length;
  var row = tab.insertRow(rowcount);
  row.insertCell(0).innerText = ino;
  row.insertCell(1).innerText = iname;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2>Add or Update Item</h2>
  <form id="addform" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="additembox">
      <label>Item No.     </label><input id="itemno" type="text" name="id" pattern="#\d\d\d" title="#xxx, x=digits">
    </div>
    <div class="additembox">
      <label>Item Name    </label><input id="itemname" type="text" name="iname">
    </div>
    <div class="additembox">
      <label>Price    </label><input id="price" type="text" name="price">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Update">
    <button id="sub" type="button" onclick="addr()">Add</button>

  </form>
</div>
<table id="addtable">
  <tr>
    <th>Sl. no</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Hotel</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here when you kept the button inside the form , it changes the URL and therefore you are not getting the expected output . 

In my code , i have put the `addbutton` outside the form and then it works completely fine .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Add or Update Item</h2>
    <form id="addform" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="additembox">
        <label>Item No.     </label><input id="itemno" type="text" name="id" title="#xxx, x=digits">
      </div>
      <div class="additembox">
        <label>Item Name    </label><input id="itemname" type="text" name="iname">
      </div>
      <div class="additembox">
        <label>Price    </label><input id="price" type="text" name="price">
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="Update">

    </form>
      <button id="sub" onClick="addr(this)">Add</button>
  </div>
  <table id="addtable">
    <tr><th>Sl. no</th><th>Item</th><th>Hotel</th><th>Price</th></tr>   
  </table>
</body>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function addr(value){
      console.log(value);
    var tab = document.getElementById('addtable');
    //getting form values
    var ino=document.getElementById('itemno').value;
    var iname=document.getElementById('itemname').value;
    var p=document.getElementById('price').value;
    var rowcount = tab.rows.length;
    var row = tab.insertRow(rowcount);
    console.log(rowcount , row);
    row.insertCell(0).innerText = ino;
    row.insertCell(1).innerText = iname;
    row.insertCell(2).innerText = p;
  }
    </script>
```

Check out my code .

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer . Welcome . @VineetK